# Out of bounds error using ArrayList.get() API, to access individual elements by its index value?

Tags: java, class

```
    roomArray.add(new Room(bed, kitchen, accessible, coffee, roomNumber));
    bookingReport();

}

public  void bookingReport()
{
    System.out.println(roomArray.get(4));
}
```

I want this to print the roomNumber a user has entered, however I receive an out of bounds error. What is the issue? Using get(4) the value at index 4, roomNumber should be returned.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `.get(3)`, being zero-indexed and all.

Comment: anything except .get(0) returns an error. roomArray is also a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've added other `Room` objects, it looks like in this code `roomArray` only has one `Room` object that was created with this - `new Room(bed, kitchen, accessible, coffee, roomNumber)`

If you try `roomArray.get(0)`, you'll probably get that room you want, but then you need an accessor method to get the `roomNumber`

Basically in your `Room` class:

```
public class Room
{
    private int roomNum;

    //I'm guessing what your constructor looks like based on your code, but I don't know the types
    public Room(boolean hasBed, String roomName, boolean isAccessible, boolean hasCoffee, int roomNumber)
    {
        roomNum = roomNumber;
    }

    //Here is your accessor method
    public int getRoomNumber()
    {
        return roomNum;
    }
}
```

Then in your calling code you can access that with this:

```
System.out.println(roomArray.get(0).getRoomNumber());
```

Comment: yep, if I use roomArray.get(0) it prints the bed, kitchen, accessible, coffee, and roomNumbers all on one line. How can I create the accessor method for just roomNumber? roomArray is also a list

Comment: I've updated my answer, basically once you get the room you want from the array, which in this case is the kitchen, you then have to call your accessor method to access the kitchen's attributes. In my example I called that method `getRoomNumber`.